# How can i get all user from firebase? And display in UI

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to get all user from firebase. And I want to display there name,email and other. How can I do it.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: on the client or in the cloud functions? You need to give us more information to be able to help you out